# Getting value array on input:chechbox

Tags: php, codeigniter, checkbox

Why in following PHP code output `var_dump` for checkbox(`$service_un`) in offset[1] is empty?

this variable(`$service_un`) get values `checkbox_un` in following HTML code that are as array but not know why in output `var_dump` on offset[1] values `input:name="checkbox_un[1][]"` are empty. how can fix it?

```
array(2) {
    [0] = > array(2) {
        [0] = > string(7)"Minibar" [1] = > string(12)"Teahouse"
    }[1] = > array(2) {
        [0] = > string(0)"" [1] = > string(0)""
    }
}
```

Codes:

```
<input type="text" name="name_un[]" value="jack">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_un[0][]" value="Minibar">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_un[0][]" value="Teahouse">

<input type="text" name="name_un[]" value="jim">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_un[1][]" value="Television">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_un[1][]" value="Foreign">

<?php
$name_un        = $this->input->post('name_un');
$service_un     = $this->input->post('checkbox_un');

var_dump($service_un); // This output

?>
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, you should use associative array indices instead of numerical, it will make your code easier to understand and debug down the line! :)

Comment: Yes i uese of it in next setup, and put it in post by comment, but @hakre remove they.

Comment: @Alicia Cibrian: That code was commented out, otherwise I would take the stance that this question is a duplicate. Feel free to link your other question that is related if you think that helps to understand this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkbox values are only set (to the value in the HTML input tag), if the checkbox has been selected (the checkmark was set).

As long as it doesn't, the offset will not be set. [Try it for yourself](http://codepad.viper-7.com/JPDnVD).